# FirebaseMessagingService extended service class destroyed in android 7.1.1 devices

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set the broadcast receiver for the actionbuttons click events and registered the receiver in FirebaseMessagingService oncreate() method and unregistered the receiver in ondestroy() method so the action buttons click event not working. this issue happening only in an android version lesser than oreo

```
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
//        create the notification action button listener
       notificationButtonClickReceiver = new NotificationButtonClickReceiver();
//        add actions for the receiver
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
       intentFilter.addAction(action1);
       intentFilter.addAction(action2);
       registerReceiver(notificationButtonClickReceiver, intentFilter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();        unregisterReceiver(notificationButtonClickReceiver);
   }
```

Comment: try to print log on action button click event. Maybe issue is in receiver only....

Comment: the onreceive () method of broadcast receiver not called when the action button click

Comment: my issue is the service which has the broadcast receiver is destroyed

Comment: can you share complete code of your receiver and service

Comment: Have you added the service in the manifest file ?

Comment: I have added the service in the manifest file without any intent filter actions

Comment: and added the actions in the manifest files its works fine

Comment: @Rohini from android 8.0 there are certain limitation on background execution https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background. So you have to find another place for unregisterReceiver().

Comment: ya thanks, I have fixed this issue but adding the actions in the manifest file for android version 7.1.1 and for android oreo I had registered the receiver in my service class