# FirebaseMessagingService is destroyed too fast

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've added FCM to my app but faced with strange behavior - the inheritor of `FirebaseMessagingService` is destroyed almost immediately.
This behavior is reproducible on the real device (Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1) but on the emulator, everything works fine. Service works as expected and is not destroyed almost immediately.

As a workaround, I tried to start my own service in `onMessageReceived` method of `FirebaseMessagingService` inheritor. This works for the cases when the app is in foreground. In this case, my backing service starts and works. But if the app is killed my backing service is not started and this may be expected behavior from Android's perspective.

Seems that the only solution is to set some flag from the `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived()` and start some checker service on the app startup. Its purpose is to check pending operations once per a second (for example) and do the actual work.
This allows covering the case when push comes both in the foreground and background of the application.

There is a similar issue
[FirebaseMessagingService extended service class destroyed in android 7.1.1 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963979/firebasemessagingservice-extended-service-class-destroyed-in-android-7-1-1-devic)

I use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  What you're describing right now is very abstract.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue and observe what you're observing.

Answer (score 0):

Has similar issues. Disabling battery optimization for the app helped in my case.

Comment: No effect in my case :(

Comment: Have you installed the same Android version on your emulator?

Comment: nope, it's fresher. I think the bug is reproducible till some specific OS version